# jQuery DataTable Sort US Date String

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, datatables

I'm working on a project where I am receiving a date for a jQuery DataTable as a string  format (mm/dd/yyyy). When I do a sort it sorts it like a string which causes causes it to be grouped in month order which is incorrect.  I would like to use 'sType: date' to handle the sorting but since it is not a date object it won't sort it.  Is there a way I can parse it to a date as it is being added into the data table?

I did find another way of doing this and sorting it properly but it only works in browsers other than ie8 (the table has ~1000 rows and it causes the script timeout error, chrome does it instantly)

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-asc'] = function(a,b) { 
            if($(a).text()=="" && $(b).text()==""){
                return 0;
            }
            else if($(a).text()=="" || $(b).text()==""){
                return $(a).text()=="" ? -1 : 1;
            }
            else{
                var x = new Date($(a).text());
                var y = new Date($(b).text());
                return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0)); 
            }
    }; 

    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-desc'] = function(a,b) {
        if($(a).text()=="" && $(b).text()==""){
                return 0;
        }
        else if($(a).text()=="" || $(b).text()==""){
            return $(a).text()=="" ? 1 : -1;
        }
        else{
            var x = new Date($(a).text());
            var y = new Date($(b).text());
            return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ?  -1 : 0)); 
       }
    };
```

I can then use this with

```
"sType": 'us_date'
```

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this barely working in IE8 without causing a page timeout.  It takes ~2 seconds to sort ~1000 records with 14 columns. (5 hidden columns).  Chrome does it instantly.

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-pre'] = function(a){
    if($(a).text()==""){
        return "19000101" * 1;
    }
    else{
        var usDatea = $(a).text().split('/');
        return (usDatea[2] + usDatea[0] + usDatea[1]) * 1;
    }
}
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-desc'] = function(a,b) {
   return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ?  -1 : 0));
};
```

Comment: +1, yes - this is a good solution. You should accept your own answer, possibly helping other people in the future, also marking it as solved.